# New in sets: How to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes in java

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator, set

I am new to sets and I found this problem in a book:

Implement the sieve of Eratosthenes: a method for computing prime numbers, known to the ancient Greeks. Choose an n. This method will compute all prime numbers up to n. First insert all numbers from 2 to n into a set. Then erase all multiples of 2 (except 2); that is, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, …. Erase all multiples of 3; that is, 6, 9, 12, 15, …. Go up to . Then print the set.

I have written this code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SieveOfEratosthenes {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.print(generatePrime(20));
    }

    public static Set generatePrime(int n){
        Set<Integer> primes = new TreeSet<>();
        Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();

        //generate all numbers up to n and add them to the set
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
            primes.add(i);
        }

        //for numbers up to root n
        for (int f = 2; f <= Math.sqrt(n); f++){
            while (iter.hasNext()){
                int current = iter.next();
                if (current % f == 0 && current != 2){
                    primes.remove(current);

                }
            }

        }

        return primes;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the code in the while loop doesn't implement. When I debugged the program I found that hasNext() is returning null. I couldn't figure out the reason of doing so although the list contains the numbers.

This is the output that I get from the code:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the `Iterator` **before** you add elements to the `Set` when you should be creating it **after** (inside the for-loop):

```
Set<Integer> primes = new TreeSet<>();

//generate all numbers up to n and add them to the set
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    primes.add(i);
}

//for numbers up to root n
for (int f = 2; f <= Math.sqrt(n); f++){
    Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();
```

Also, I recommend changing the following:

```
primes.remove(current);
```

To:

```
iter.remove();
```

To avoid any `ConcurrentModificationException`s.

---

Lastly, it seems you still have an issue where `3` is not in the resulting `Set`, which you'll have to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I could find the problem for the number 3